# How do get Phalcon Session from the DI in a standalone class

Tags: session, phalcon

I have a class that I have created in my Phalcon project. I want to get the `session` service from the `DI` so that I can check if a variable is set.

I have tried:

```
$di = Phalcon\DI::getDefault();
echo $di->get("session")->get("user_id");
exit;
```

However it comes back saying `A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()`

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple, Phalcon\Mvc\User\Plugin;

class JsonReturnObject extends Plugin
```

My session service is registered like this:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\View;
use Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Url as UrlProvider;
use Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt as VoltEngine;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Metadata\Memory as MetaData;
use Phalcon\Session\Adapter\Files as SessionAdapter;  
use Phalcon\Flash\Session as FlashSession;       
use Phalcon\Events\Manager as EventsManager;  

//setup the dependency injection
$di = new FactoryDefault();

//setup the session
$di->set('session', function() {
    $session = new SessionAdapter();
    $session->start();
    return $session;
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try registering the session as not a shared component like this:

```
$di->set(
    'session',
    function () {
        $session = new \Phlacon\Session\Adapter\Files();
        $session->start();

        return $session;
     }
 );
```

Note the third parameter is not `true` on the `$di->set()`

Alternatively use `$di->set()` instead of `$di->setShared()`

Comment: Thanks. See my update- my session is more or less registered the same way.

Comment: So something is starting a session in your app before the session is registered and started. Try putting the session registration in the DI at the top of your bootstrap code or services.php file - see if that helps

Comment: See my edit- that didn't help unfortunately. In many other parts of the code, I have no problem in getting the session so not sure what the go is!

Comment: To me, it seems that the session is trying to be started again when I call `$di->get("session")->get("user_id");` in my code, because that is when it says that the session is already started (as it should be from when it was started in the di registration)

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to set the service to shared using `setShared`.